# Share feed on selected friends wall

Tags: facebook, share

I just got a request to make a solution where the user can select some friends, and post a suggestion to their wall. Is that "legal", what do you call this and is it going to work with Timeline, when this is coming soon.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy documents are here: http://developers.facebook.com/policy 
If you follow those policies there's nothing preventing you from asking a user to post on another user's profile/timeline

Comment: Okay thanks. But what is the function called, and will it still work on the new time line?

Comment: It's just a regular Graph API POST to `/{user id}/feed` or `/{user id}/posts` with the appropriate parameters - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts